# How to remove a branch from the "Your branches" section

Tags: github

When you click on project, and then on branches, it has `Default branch`, `Your branches`, `Active branches`, and `Stale branches` sections. In the `Your branches` section, there are branches that I once worked on, but am no longer working on. Other people are still using the branches so the branches should not be deleted.

Is there a way for me to remove those branches from my `Your branches` section, just for some general cleanup?

Edit:
Just to clarify, the branch has been deleted locally but is still in the `Your branches` section. And as said above I do not want to delete it remotely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: Nope, the branch has been deleted locally. I don't want to delete it remotely, but remove it from the `Your branches` section